# How to convert my lotus 2000r into a single speed

Tags: single-speed

Hello everyone I bought a lotus 2000r and am currently converting it into a single speed.

(Generic photo of a lotus 2000r from google images)
[image]

I wanted to know if I can put this wheel from Amazon

[image]
[https://www.amazon.com/Wheel-Rear-1-1-Silver-Bolt/dp/B000AO3GK2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AO3GK2)

Then use a cog like this
[image]

http://www.jensonusa.com/Shimano-DX-Single-Speed-Freewheel
on that wheel. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The keepers of the cog would strongly condemn such a defiling of a road bike.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Carson. We recommend that all new users do our [tour], to see how we work here. There are a bunch of related question under the [tag:single-speed] tag, for example http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/how-to-convert-a-multi-speed-bike-to-single-speed-with-coaster-brake and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16551/planning-on-building-a-fixed-gear-single-speed-from-an-old-schwinn-world-what-n and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25142/trying-to-build-first-fixie

Comment: Looks like fully functional road bike. Why do you what to downgrade it ?

Comment: This question is now 5 years old.  What did you end up doing?  How did it work, and what did you wish you already knew ?

Answer (score 2):

You should get away with the new freewheel by itself, simply take the freewheel off the current wheel and fit that.

You will need a chain tool to shorten your chain, and depending on the dropouts you may need a chain tensioner, or you might be lucky.

Note that while you don't need new chainrings, you won't be able to shift front gear without either a chain tensioning arm, or leaving the rear derailleur in place, to take up the slack.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely have to adjust the chainline regarding...

- crank arm, front sprocket position on axis
- rear hub in rear wheel: It should be centered. True it via spokes and/or insert new spokes.

  - if not (enough), you can level the sprocket w/ spacers
  - always check the centering: rim in frame. You might need spacers for the rear hub (in frame) as well.